# How to display a string variable in a specific number format like "#,0.##"

Tags: c#

I have a typed dataset with a column called price, which is of string datatype. And I'm showing this via ultrgrid/datagrid

How can I show the price in number format. 
For example: price ==123456
in the grid it should be like 12,354,56

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx

Comment: Shouldn't price be a numeric type?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var a = price.ToString("##,###,##");
```

[Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

[**Custom Numeric Format Strings**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx)!

Answer (score 0):

Look at some of the related links to the right of the screen.  Some of them even ask the same question as you !